# Can't apt update

Tags: apt, 20.04

I'm losing my mind over this. For two days, I can't seem to be able to have apt working.

I have a VM with Ubuntu 20.04.2 on it. All I want to do is to have to have `apt` with the official Ubuntu repo. This is what I get when I perform an `apt update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.il-ta.kamatera.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to mirror.il-ta.kamatera.com:80 (185.229.226.227), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm getting this error no matter what I do, even if I'm using the default sourcelist: `cat /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list > /etc/apt/sources.list`, same thing.

There is an internet connection. I can ping google.com. I barley have any tools on it as apt can't install most of the things.

Does anyone happen to know what's going on? Huge thanks ahead.

---

EDIT: While I can ping the mirror, I can't telnet into it on port 80. I can however, telnet to that from my workstation, which has the same DNS/Gateway, which leads me to believe it's related to something in the VM itself. I had a problem with the proxy before but I solved it by deleting `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`. The file was there because the VM was deployed by MAAS.

Comment: can you show us the whole output from `sudo apt update` please.

Comment: Thanks for the response! [This is the whole output](https://pastebin.com/GQPRGi8k)

Comment: The mirror works (tested it). Can you ping the mirror? In a previous question, you mentioned that you are using an apt-proxy. Might that mean all attempts to reach that domain are being blocked by your network policy?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have deleted `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`, so I assume it doesn't use proxy anymore? I'm not sure actually. Also, I found out that while I can ping that mirror, I can't telnet into it from my VM, while I can from my workstation. So I assume it's related to the VM itself as both my workstation and the VM connect to the same DNS/Gateway. I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning but the VM was deployed by MAAS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your network is only connected inside of your VMware. Please, check your network settings.

If above doesn't help then you might downloading from wrong server. 
Please, download from the main server.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm pretty sure it's not related to VMware as I am able to ping those addresses, just not telnet at port 80. If I run apt update, I get the error I mentioned in the thread, and `apt full-upgrade` returns that it did nothing (`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`)

Answer (score 0):

This is embaracing, so the DHCP leased an IP of a subnet out of range. That's it.. Sorry for wasting your time :(